# SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)returns 1

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Just wondering , anyone got that issue:

I'm using Visual Studio Community and after  adding class and **moving SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) from main function to Someclass.cpp** my Window is not  appearing anymore. SDL_Init returns 1.

I thought it's just my code related issue but I copied tutor code and that's not working as well in my environment.(his eclipse works as it should) It used to work properly when SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) was called from main.cpp.
I was trying to add additional dependencies in Project/Settings/Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies
but no success:( Maybe I was doing something wrong.
SDL Window still  doesn't appear.

This is  the  function which initialize SDL video:

```
SDL_Window* Screen::Init(uint32_t w, uint32_t h, uint32_t mag){
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO))
{
    std::cout << "Error SDL_Init Failed" << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    return nullptr;
}

mWidth = w;
mHeight = h;
moptrWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Arcade", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, mWidth * mag, mHeight * mag, 0);

if (moptrWindow)
{
    mnoptrWindowSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(moptrWindow);
    SDL_PixelFormat* pixelFormat = mnoptrWindowSurface->format;
    Color::InitColorFormat(pixelFormat);
    mClearColor = Color::Black();
    mBackBuffer.Init(pixelFormat->format, mWidth, mHeight);
    mBackBuffer.Clear(mClearColor);
}

return moptrWindow;
```

}

The main function from where Init is called:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){
Screen theScreen;
theScreen.Init(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, MAGNIFICATION);
theScreen.Draw(SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2, Color::Yellow());
theScreen.SwapScreens();

SDL_Event sdlEvent;
bool running = true;

while (running)
{
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&sdlEvent))
    {
        switch (sdlEvent.type)
        {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            running = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}

return 0;
```

}

Output is:

1

C:\Users\MyPC\projects\drawing-line\Debug\drawing-line.exe (process 13032) exited with code 0.
Press any key to close this window . . .

If anyone wants to try my code there is link to google drive:
[that's whole project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14VUUVEpRNAbcZY1iUfwfOerGs6tz9BGP)

Thank you.
Luke

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you can, can you please edit your post to be a bit more clear/precise in what you're asking? It looks like you just copied some text from somewhere (hence the `0 Lukasz · Lecture 66 · 34 minutes ago Hi,`. 

Can you add some code showing what you're attempting to do vs what you're getting? Simply saying that `SDL_Init returns 1` doesn't really mean much to any of us. Clearly this is C++, you should add a tag to reflect that so that C++ developers can answer your question.

Comment: [SDL_GetError()](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetError) might tell you why it failed.

Comment: As a new user, start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your code problem, please extract and provide a [mcve].

Comment: I supplied some code related and gave a link to all files of the project.

Comment: SDL_GetError () doesn't give any output

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I resolved the problem. I changed all settings to X64 and got rid of **const** in: int main(int argc,const char* argv[]). Now works as it should.Took me while:)